# Embeding python in Vala

Tags: python, embed, vala, pygobject

I want to embed the Python interpreter into a program written in Vala to allow for some runtime scripting.  I can run parts of my vala code from Python using Introspection, and I've found a rudimentary example of embedding the interpreter in Python here: https://gist.github.com/astagi/1282808.

That example does not show how to pass an instance of an object in Vala to the interpreter and back.  In the example of how to embed Python (http://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding) a variable of type long is converted to/form the python type using using something like this:

```
PyObject *pvalue = PyLong_FromLong(foo);
```

and

```
long foo=PyLong_asLong(pvalue);
```

The question is what are the equivalent functions for a variable in Vala of type GLib.Object [a GObject in C form].

Comment: I'm a little confused here.  What's lead you to believe that GObject can be automatically marshalled to a Python object?

Comment: Here's my reasoning so far: I can write a class called `SomeClass` in Vala that inherits from GObject. I can compile SomeClass to a shared library, and import that to python using `from gi.repository import SomeClass`.  When  SomeClass is instantiated in python, the resulting object is actually a GObject, wrapped in a PyObject (is that incorrect?). With the python interpreter embed in a Vala program, the user might run a python script that creates an instance of SomeClass `sc=SomeClass()`  but its a PyObject managed by the interpreter.  How do I get the GObject in `sc` back to main program

Comment: This sounds more like a PyGObject question than a Python question.

Comment: As I've investigated more, I've been coming to the same conclusion.  I added the pygobject tag to reflect that.

Comment: Why not just use libpeas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with libpeas.  I'll take a look at it.  Can you point me to an example of a project that uses this to implement a python scripting interface to a program written I'm vala?

Comment: libpeas is a language-agnostic plugin system based on GObject.  If that's what you're trying to do it's likely a good fit -- gedit uses libpeas, for example.

Comment: @ajg144 Did you finally find a solution?